# In Matlab, how can I define an indicator variable activating a certain part of a function?

Tags: matlab

For matlab, I am trying to define two likelihood functions, one which activates if the observation is endogenous, and one that activates if it is exogenous. So far, I have:

```
(End == 1) {Likelihood function for ENDOGENOUS variable goes here} 
+
(End == 0) {Likelihood function for EXOGENOUS variable goes here}
```

Here the `End` variable in my dataset goes to 1 if the observation is endogenous and 0 is the observation is exogenous 
Would the above be adequate to define a function in matlab?

Thank you!

Comment: Just an aside: try and avoid naming variables that are similar to MATLAB keywords.  In this case, `End` versus the MATLAB `end` which is used to _terminate block of code, or indicate last array index_ (from [end](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define End on each value of your domain and define LEN and LEX on every point in your domain you can write the combined likelihood function using dot times...

```
L = (End == 1).*LEN + (End == 0).*LEX;
```

where LEN is endgoenous likelihood.